# Why is my tab screen rerendering if there is no change in fiveElements?

Tags: react-native, tabnavigator

```
<Tab.Screen 
        name="Sheet" 
        children={()=><SheetScreen fiveElements={fiveElements}/>}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Sheet',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="information-outline" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
/>
```

Why is my tab screen rerendering if there is no change in the fiveElements state?

Answer (score 1):

Would be best if you use the Screen this way:

```
<Tab.Screen 
        name="Sheet" 
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Sheet',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="information-outline" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
> 
props => <SheetScreen {...props} fiveElements={fiveElements}/>
</Tab.Screen>
```